# Is there any difference between these three uses of DATEADD?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

All three statements below return the same result. So I'm struggling to see what the difference is between using dayofyear, day and weekday. Am I missing something or are they all equivalent?

```
   SELECT DATEADD(dayofyear,1,'20111231')
   SELECT DATEADD(day,1,'20111231')
   SELECT DATEADD(weekday,1,'20111231')
```

They all return 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In that use, no they return the same. Though "day" feels natural for this use.

The difference comes in (e.g.) DATEPART:

```
SELECT DATEPART(dayofyear,'20111231') -- 365
SELECT DATEPART(day,'20111231') -- 31
SELECT DATEPART(weekday,'20111231') --7
```

Here's the [MSDN ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) on it:

> dayofyear , day, and weekday return
>   the same value.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATEADD(dayofyear,1,'20111231')
SELECT DATEADD(day,1,'20111231')
SELECT DATEADD(weekday,1,'20111231')
```

They are all equivalent.

The date parts month, year, day, hour are all units of measure in their own right.  However, dayofyear and weekday are not.  Yet you can look at it this way -

```
the datepart "month" changes when the month changes,
the datepart "hour" changes when the hour changes,
the datepart "dayofyear" changes (by 1) when the day changes,
the datepart "weekday" changes (by 1) when the day changes
the datepart "day" changes (by 1) when the day changes
```

So you have to argue that the "unit of" *dayofyear* is equal to one day. To DateAdd a "dayofyear" part, it will increase the date by 1 day.

If you are starting with a date variable or date/time column, you can just add 1 to it, e.g.

```
dateadd(d, 1, @date)  ==  @date + 1
```

It won't work with date literals

```
select '2010-12-12' + 1   -- attempts to add the string '2010-12-12' to 1
```

One would have to cast/convert

```
select cast('2010-12-12' as datetime) + 1
```

But by that stage, you might as well use dateadd, which implicitly casts the 3rd argument

```
select dateadd(d, 1, '2010-12-12')  -- 2010-12-13
select dateadd(d, 1, 40522)         -- 2010-12-13
```